# django datetimefield: __str__ give different time from admin display

Tags: python, django, datetime, strftime

i am trying to setup the **str**() to display a datetimefield in admin site. but it give me a different time in different pages.
the code is like:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name + \
        " ordered on " + \
        str(self.order_date.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S"));
```

it give a time like 20171027-22:28:40 in the list of My_model. However, "Oct. 27, 2017, 3:28 p.m." is displayed if i click into the entry as the pictures. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUPBE.gif)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbnxF.gif)

Comment: What is your problem. What format you want it to be ?

Comment: Are 20171027-22:28:40 and Oct. 27, 2017, 3:28 p.m. the same time?

Comment: I guess one is with and one without timezone. You should add the timezone to the format string to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method you overwrite `__str__` 
is for an entire record, instead of displaying for example 'Order: id' the representation you have define which will be fetching.

So, the first solution is, you can type this in **setting.py** file

```
from django.conf.locale.en import formats as en_formats
from django.conf.locale.fr import formats as fr_formats
#....

en_formats.DATETIME_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S" 
fr_formats.DATETIME_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"
```